# How to show database info in Laravel Blade with VUE

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Sorry for the next question, Im really new on VUE.

I have a button on my blade, when I do it click I want to retrieve the info of the customer depend of the ID that get on my controller, I get the ID #3 and I click on CUSTOMER INFO Button, I want to see the info of this customer from the database

This is my function on my Controller  **CustomersController.php**

```
public function showcustomers($idcustomer)
{
    $Customers = Customers::find($idcustomer);
   
    return view('showcustomer',
        ['Customers' => $Customers]);
}
```

And this is my button on Blade **showcustomer.blade.php** :

```
<div id="cita">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button v-on:click="showinfo = !showinfo"  type="button" class="w3-btn w3-blue" style="width:100%">CUSTOMER INFO</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>
<div class="container align-content-between">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12">
            <information v-if="!showinfo"></information>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My **app.js**

```
Vue.component('information', require('./components/information.vue').default);
var app = new Vue({
el: '#cita',
```

data: {
showinfo: true,
}
});

And finally my **information.vue**

```
<template>
<div id="information">
    <h4>Information {{ Customers.name }}</h4>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "information"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Please clarify, so what is your exact problem that you cannot resolve with the solution that you shared with us?

Comment: You have lot of things wrong there. You need to take a reading of Vue documentation again. I will try to give you hint at a time: div that is called by Vue instance (i.e. `#cita`) has to be empty. Chack that first in documentation.

Comment: Also take a look on blog [articles](https://dev.to/37shadesofgrey/setting-up-vue-in-laravel-8-580m) and YT tutorials how it (Laravel with Vue) should be set up.

Comment: @Syngularity No, doesnt work as the way I show, =(

Answer (score 0):

Standard way of doing that is you will be implementing an ajax request where your front-end or Vue will fetch the necessary information from back-end via ajax request.

Another way of achieving that is you will be using properties or attributes in VUE

from your **information.vue** add a props maybe **customerName** or **orderId** or both

```
<template>
<div id="information">

    <h4>Information {{ customerName }}</h4>
    <h4>ID {{ orderID }}</h4>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:["customerName","orderID"],
    name: "information"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

in you **showcustomer.blade.php** you can pass the data from php to your vue by adding attributes based on the property name declared on you vue template

```
<information customer-name="John Mahu" order-id="0099812-ABC" v-if="!showinfo"></information>
```

or populate from your PHP variable

```
<information customer-name="{{ $Customers->customer_name }}" order-id="{$Customers->some_order_id}" v-if="!showinfo"></information>
```

Read more about vue props
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html